# How to hide password even using fire bug?

Tags: passwords, firebug, hidden

My friend easily finding my password,using firebug..i.e when i am in login page ,my friend using inspect element to find the password element and he changes the type="password" to type="text",now its shows the password...how to avoid this????

Comment: Punch your friend. He'll learn not to do it after enough punches.

Comment: Seriously though, I don't understand what the problem is. Can you clarify?

Comment: Have you own dedicated windows/unix/mac user account with a strong password.

Comment: I've changed the tags on this question. It has nothing to do with PHP (the original tag).

Comment: Don't leave your browser sitting on the login screen with your username and password entered. It's also not a good idea to write your password on a postit note and stick it on your monitor where your friend can see it... the solution to both problems is to poke his eyes out so that he can't see, and then change your password

Comment: @pekka -- he knows my net banking passwords and so i need to change password frequently

Comment: How about not letting your friend know your secret passwords?

Comment: I noticed the same thing and was interested to see what people were saying about the subject of passwords in console. I took everybody's advice and murdered my friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously your friend can only do this if he can get to your PC while it's got the page loaded and mess around in Firebug. And then, since all he's done is make the password characters visible, to find out what your password is he has to stand over your shoulder to watch you type it.

This sounds more like a prank than a serious hack attempt. There are much worse ways to get hacked than that, especially if someone has direct access to your PC while you're logged in.

If you're writing a web site, and you're *really* worried about this sort of thing, there are steps you can take to prevent it.

For example, instead of asking the user to enter their whole password, you could give them a set of text boxes and ask them to enter just a few random characters from their password -- eg you could ask them to enter the first, fourth and eighth characters. This means that even if someone was watching what they typed, they'd only find out part of the password, which would be useless to them next time when the site asked for a different set of characters.

There are, of course, flaws in this scheme too, and it's a lot more of a hassle for the user, but it is considered more secure.

But typically it's only banking sites and the like that go to this sort of length to protect passwords. Most normal sites don't need this sort of level of security.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to .. not store your passwords in your browser.